# How do i return related data in web api so that the json does not return the null values

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

```
namespace POS_Backend_.Controllers
{
    public class hotelapiController : ApiController
    {
        private POSDBEntities db = new POSDBEntities();

        // GET: api/hotelapi
        public IList<HotelsDetailsDto> GetHotels()
        {
            return db.Hotels.Select(p => new HotelsDetailsDto 
            {   Id = p.Id,
                Name = p.Name,
                Address = p.Address,
                Description = p.Description,
                Offering = p.Offering,
                Gps = p.Gps,
                NumberOfRooms = p.NumberOfRooms,
                Commission = p.Commission,
                Rating = p.Rating,    
                HotelTypeName=p.HotelTypeName,
                Image = p.Image,
                LocationId = p.LocationId,
            }).ToList();
        }
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Meilkles",
    "Address": "samora machel avenue",
    "Description": "luxury hotel",
    "Offering": "swimming",
    "Gps": "3672.22",
    "NumberOfRooms": 5444,
    "Commission": 65,
    "HotelTypeName": "Lodge",
    "Rating": 3,
    "LocationId": 1,
    "Image": "~/Banners/download(7).jpg",
    "Comments": null,
    "Favourites": null,
    "Location": null,
    "HotelType": null,
    "Locations": null
}
```

Comment: returns json like this 
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Meilkles",
    "Address": "samora machel avenue",
    "Description": "luxury hotel",
    "Offering": "swimming",
    "Gps": "3672.22",
    "NumberOfRooms": 5444,
    "Commission": 65,
    "HotelTypeName": "Lodge",
    "Rating": 3,
    "LocationId": 1,
    "Image": "~/Banners/download(7).jpg",
    "Comments": null,
    "Favourites": null,
    "Location": null,
    "HotelType": null,
    "Locations": null
  },

Comment: I edited your question to add the result, this should be an edit, not a comment. If you have more informations, edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class Hotel without the HotelsDetailsDto properties that are null, then let class HotelsDetailsDto inherit from Hotel. Return a list instead.

This would work, unless HotelsDetailsDto is dynamically generated via linq to SQL. In this case, provide a mapping between Hotel and HotelsDetailsDto to generate a List

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the WebApiConfig:

This code remove all `null` property when json returned at application level

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore};
```

if you want to remove `null` property from a specific model then use this code:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string Comments{ get; set; }
```

Hope this help.